# ¿Alguien me puede decir como puedo hacer dos grupos de este código que de las 65 imágenes que genera esto que las imágenes tenga diferentes fondos?

Tags: php, wordpress

He llegado crear 60 códigos(he incluso aparte he llegado utilizar mas código porque lo intentado con funciones en functions.php o con jquery en un archivo js por probar no quedo nada)  sin éxito lo he divido entre etiquetados, categorías y subcategorías pero si éxito ni uno porque o me eliminaba algunas imágenes me las multiplicaba ya no se que hacer y necesito que las imágenes que genera esto en la pagina de mi WordPress algunas sean moradas o otras naranjas claro como fondo de las imágenes sin que me toque mas nada que esa es otra no paraba de tocarme los figures o los titulos h2 y ahora he puesto mi primer código que cree alguien sabe que hacer como para dividirlo o lo que sea para que note diferencia y ponga los colores correspondiente sin tocar otra cosa que no sea de las etiquetas de img.

```
printf( '<main class="container  main">' );
if( have_posts() ):
    while( have_posts() ):
        the_post();
        
        $template_html = '
            <a href="%s">
                <figure class="item  i-b  ph100  sm33  md20  lg15 main-items">
                    <img class="fondo" src="%s">
                    <figcaption><h2>%s</h2></figcaption>
                </figure>
            </a>
        ';

        printf( 
            $template_html,
            get_permalink(),
            main_image_url( 'thumbnail' ),
            get_the_title()
        );

    endwhile;
else:
    printf( '<p class="error">No hay entradas</p>' );
endif;
rewind_posts();

printf( '</main>' );``
```

Comment: de qué depende el fondo? es un meta, una categoría un autor?

Comment: Depende de subcategorías el otro código que hice son dos y una tiene que tener en las etiquetas img fondo naranja y el otro morado pero salieron horrible nunca conseguía que funcionara

Answer (score 0):

La función que puede servirte en este caso es [`post_class()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_class/) que genera un string con una lista de classes css derivadas del id, las categorías, etiquetas y formato del post.

Dependiendo de cómo y qué quieras estilar y si eso se cascadea a otras partes del sitio, las classes las podes aplicar en el `<a>`, el `figure` o `img`.

Para evitar que los css que definas afecten otras partes del sitio podes incluir una class especifica de este fragmento pasandolo como argumento ( puede ser un string o un array ) `<?php post_class( 'class-name' ); ?>`.

Todo junto quedaría algo así:

```
printf( '<main class="container  main">' );
if( have_posts() ):
  while( have_posts() ):
    the_post();

    $template_html = '
  <a href="%s" %s >
    <figure class="item  i-b  ph100  sm33  md20  lg15 main-items">
      <img class="fondo" src="%s">
      <figcaption><h2>%s</h2></figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
    ';

  printf(
    $template_html,
    get_permalink(),
    post_class('confondo'),
    main_image_url( 'thumbnail' ),
    get_the_title()
  );
  endwhile;
else:
  printf( '<p class="error">No hay entradas</p>' );
endif;
rewind_posts();

printf( '</main>' );
```

Debería aplicarle al `<a>` que contiene el `img` algo tipo `class="confondo post-2345 category-unacategoria tag-unaetiqueta format-elformato"`por cada post del haveposts.

Luego en css vas targeteando el elemento deseado ( en este caso `img`):

```css
/* default */
.confondo img { background-color: none }

.confondo.category-unacategoria img { background-color: purple }
.confondo.category-otracategoria img { background-color: orange }
```

Anteponiendo el `.confondo` te aseguras que ese css se aplique sólo en ese snippet y no al resto del site donde puede que se imprima el `class="category-unacategoria"`.

Comment: Pero son subcategorías es posible mede category poner subcategory es algo asin? y gracias por la ayuda es la primera vez que programo y hago un proyecto en wodrpess es mas diferente de todo lo que llegado hacer

Comment: va a listar todas las entradas en las taxonomias a las que pertenezca, para "category" vas a ver la categoría padre y las sub categorías, y así para todas las taxonomías por ejemplo si el post es un producto de woocommerce vas a ver las categorias y subcategorias de esa taxonomia: `$ wp eval 'echo post_class('confondo',88781 );'` -> `class="confondo post-88781 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-school-store product_cat-clothing first instock shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-variable has-default-attributes"`

Comment: en ese ejemplo `product_cat` es la taxonomia, `school-store` es una sub categoría, `clothing` es una sub sub categoría

Comment: lo he resuelto de otra manera le he añadido una funcion de if que si estaba el fondo para tal subcategoria que lo quite y ponga otro y hay funcionado pero gracias por la idea quiza en un futuro lo haga asin es que estuve probando de todo y la verdad me resulto comoda esa